# How do I get the n-th element in a LinkedList<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, linked-list

How can I get the n-th element of a LinkedList instance? Is there a built-in way or I might need to introduce my own implementation? For example an extension method?

Thanks

Comment: First of all, why? Sure you need a linked list?

Comment: I have one example of InsertedSortList which uses methods like InsertAt(int i) on a LinkedList data structure. That is why I wanted to ask.

Comment: Is it SO or MSDN Documentation?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The [`ElementAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233.aspx) extension method will do it:

```
// This is 0-based of course
var value = linkedList.ElementAt(n);
```

Don't forget this is an O(n) operation because `LinkedList<T>` doesn't provide any more efficient way of accessing an item by index. If you need to do this regularly, it suggests that you shouldn't be using a linked list to start with.

Comment: Microsoft, please, add the complexity in the documentation :)

Comment: @Jon not be nitpicking, but is it necessary that if I implement `IList<T>`, the indexing operation cant be `O(n)`?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the ElementAt() enumerable extension method. The reason LinkedList doesn't support random access natively is because it's a rather inefficient operation for the data structure. If you're going to be doing it often you should think about using a more appropriate data structure.

Answer (score 3):

I needed to get the second element of my list (to update a value on the 1st item based on the 2nd)

Assuming you're taking the necessary steps to ensure you do have two items you can simply do this :

```
list.First.Next.Value
```

Comment: Lol this is so silly!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with LINQ as in `list.ElementAt(n)` or `list.Skip(n - 1).First()` , but if you find yourself making indexed access into a linked list you are probably doing something wrong (linked lists do not efficiently support this operation). Perhaps another data structure would be more appropriate?