# Using a Linked List or Array for Monopoly?

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, linked-list

I'm making a Monopoly game for a school project, written in C++. The first thing I'm working on is implementing the board. It's intuitive to me that each tile will be an object holding information and functions and whatnot, but I cannot decide whether these should be contained in a linked list or array.

It made sense for a linked list because i could simply have the last tile point to the first, but it also seems more efficient to use an array since I can instantly access Tile[5] for example.

Can anybody clarify as to which would be better for this purpose?

Comment: An array list.  Best of both worlds

Comment: Why not an `std::array`?  It's not like the board is going to change size.

Comment: In this case an array is best choice. This question here answers how to select array vs linked list http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393556/when-to-use-a-linked-list-over-an-array-array-list

Comment: @JohnDibling what are the advantages of using this over a normal array? I would prefer to stick to what I know to keep it simple but if it will actually make this easier I can consider it.

Comment: Use an elementAt(n) method as part of your linked list. 

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10164355/how-do-i-get-the-n-th-element-in-a-linkedlistt>

Comment: @HaydenHolligan:  There is nothing to gain by using a C-style array versus usig `std::array`.  The latter is a proper C++11 container, and directly supports all that entails.  With `std::array`, there is really no reason to use C-style arrays at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- It's a fixed size.  That negates about 90% of the advantages of a linked list.
- You will NEVER be accessing it sequentially (unless, instead of dice, everybody just moves one square each time), but always randomly.  That's about 90% of the advantage of an array.
- The one reason you cite for using a linked-list is trivially handled differently. (`new_position = (current_position + roll) % 40;`)

Therefore: You unquestionably want to use an array.